# javaScript, function, priting my name (beginner)

Tags: javascript

Good evening, everyone!

I'm new to this site, I'm learning javaScript and I'm still a noob, I got stuck in this and I can't simply understand what's wrong.

I have the following instructions:

1. Write a function called nameString()
2. It should take name as a parameter.
3. The function returns a string equal to "Hi, I am" + " " + name.
4. Call nameString() by passing it your name, and use console.log to print the output.

I wrote:

```
var nameString = function (name) {return "Hi, I am" + " " + name;};
nameString (Myrrh); console.log (name);
```

But the console says`ReferenceError: Myrrh is not defined`.

I tried to write then `nameString (Myrrh); console.log (nameString);` but it didn't work either.
If I write `nameString (name); console.log (nameString);` it no longer throws that error but the console prints out `[Function]` and not the `''Hi, I am Myrrh''` message I'm supposed to get.

I'm new to functions, and as far as I understood you simply assign a value in parentheses to the parameter when you call the function, meaning, `nameString (Myrrh);` should be alright because ''Myrrh'' is the value of (name). This has perfectly worked for other exercises but won't work for this one. In addition, calling the function and logging inside the curly braces won't change anything either. And, of course, changing ''name'' inside the curly braces to something else doesn't work, either. I also changed `var nameString = function (name)` to `function nameString (name)` since they seem to mean the same or something similar (not sure about the difference) but it still throws the same error.

I'm stuck, no idea how to solve this. I'm probably missing the silliest detail as a beginner but no matter what I change it throws an error.

PS: If it helps anything, it's an exercise from Code Academy.

Comment: btw looks like what you're missing is quotes around the myrrh: `nameString ("Myrrh");`

Comment: It is early morning here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to an object named `Myrrh`, Strings should be passed in between quotes.
Also I noticed you didn't asigned the return value of the function to any variable:

```
var name = nameString ("Myrrh");
console.log(name);
```

Comment: Thank you! Though I had tried the quotes before it hadn't worked either, it printed blank or printed [Function: nameString]. But what was missing was the var name part, now it did print :). Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the was what you were looking for, consider accepting it by clicking he "accept mark" below the rating.